# Kria KV260 clock doesn't work

Tags: fpga, vhdl, clock

I'm trying to run a very basic blinking LED with VHDL on a [Kria KV260](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ds986-kv260-starter-kit) board.

led_blink.vhd:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
 
entity led_blink is
  port (
    clk      : in  std_logic;
    led  : out std_logic
    );
end led_blink;
 
architecture rtl of led_blink is
  constant c_CNT_100HZ : natural := 500000;
  signal r_CNT_100HZ : natural range 0 to c_CNT_100HZ;
  signal r_TOGGLE_100HZ : std_logic := '0';
begin
   
  p_100_HZ : process (clk) is
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      if r_CNT_100HZ = c_CNT_100HZ-1 then 
        r_TOGGLE_100HZ <= not r_TOGGLE_100HZ;
        r_CNT_100HZ    <= 0;
      else
        r_CNT_100HZ <= r_CNT_100HZ + 1;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process p_100_HZ;
 
  led <= r_TOGGLE_100HZ;
 
end rtl;
```

system.xdc:

```
set_property IOSTANDARD  LVCMOS33 [get_ports "led"]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN B11      [get_ports "led"]

set_property IOSTANDARD  LVCMOS12 [get_ports "clk"]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN C3       [get_ports "clk"]
```

The issue is that it doesn't turn on the LED; it stays off.

I added `r_TOGGLE_100HZ <= '1';` in the process block and it works, so apparently the sensitivity signal is not the issue, but when using the same assignment in `rising_edge(clk)` condition block it doesn't work, the `rising_edge(clk)` doesn't fire. I also tried with `clk'event and clk='1'`.

I tried with different delays. I should also mention the clock is 100 MHz.

Comment: are you certain that the LED stays off? ... did you check it with an oscilloscope?

Comment: @jsotola Unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscope but I tried with different delays. I should also mention the clock is 100Mhz.

Comment: don't bury the info about the clock in a comment ... add it to the question

Comment: Oscilloscope or at the very least a logic analyzer is a must to do development.